# Overriding filter with smudge and cat in git config locally

Tags: git, jupyter, cat

I have the global filter in order to scrub the output from my Jupyter notebooks. I use the following `--global` settings in git to do so:
.gitconfig:

```
filter.clean_ipynb.clean=/home/username/.scripts/ipynb_drop_output.py
filter.clean_ipynb.smudge=cat
```

.gitattributes:

```
*.ipynb filter=clean_ipynb
```

Now I have one repository where I wish to not use this filter, what is the best way to override this in the local repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `.gitattributes` or `$GIT_DIR/info/attributes` file for the one repository in which you want to override this `filter` setting,<sup>1</sup> use:

```
*.ipynb !filter
```

which reverts the `filter` setting to "unspecified".

This works for all attributes, not just `filter`.  Because `filter` only operates when it's *set* to some particular value, `-filter` would work as well; and because `filter` only takes one value, `filter=dummy` would also work, as long as you have no `filter.dummy.*` settings.  But `!filter` is the way to go.

---

<sup>1</sup>Use `.gitattributes` if you want new clones to copy this setting.  Use `$GIT_DIR/info/attributes` if you want new clones *not* to copy this setting.  This, too, is a general pattern.